# Is ther a way to open spectroscopy data file *.sp from FL Winlab Perkin Elmer into R

Tags: r, spectrum

I collect 3D excitation-emission spectra on a PerkinElmer LS-50B using FL winlab software (the classic Perkin Elmer vendor software for the device).
For this mode, the software apparently allow only to save *.sp file (specific to Perkin Elmer) and save one file per each excitation increment.
I wonder if it is possible to open a sp file in R to be able to analyze The data.

Currently, I process the data to convert it ito csv file using SpectraGryph 1.2. It nice but need some repetitive and time consuming step.Because I generate a lot of data I am looking for a automatic solution to speed up the processing.
I tried the following step:

```
#choose a sp file
f <- file.choose() 
# try to open it
df <- scan(f,skip=3)
```

I get

```
Error in read.table(f, skip = 3) : no lines available in input
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In readLines(file, skip) : line 1 appears to contain an embedded nul
2: In readLines(file, skip) : line 2 appears to contain an embedded nul
3: In readLines(file, skip) :
  incomplete final line found on 'C:\Users\...\DY02_25032021#05.sp'
```

> 

Comment: Welcome to SO. You maximize your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  may help